# RShiny SQL dataframe to table

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following code in the file `server.R` for my R Shiny app

```
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  myData <- reactive({

    conn <- odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=xxx;database=xxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx")

    q <- paste("SELECT * FROM dbo.players")

    res <- sqlQuery(channel=conn, query=q)

    res

  })

  output$tbTable <- renderTable({
    myData
  })
})
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Warning: Error in as.data.frame.default: cannot coerce class "c("reactiveExpr", "reactive")" to a data.frame
Stack trace (innermost first):
    79: as.data.frame.default
    78: as.data.frame
    77: origRenderFunc
    76: output$tbTable
     1: runApp
```

I'm new to R, and don't really understand how to do the conversion. My understanding is that res is of type data.frame, and renderTable takes a vector as an argument. It's also wrapped in a reactive function because I eventually want to make my SQL Queries depend on some reactive input. How can I fix this error?

Comment: try `myData()` in the `Render...` function

Comment: And dont forget to disconect after get data or after session end.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @patrik and @Batanichek, I came up with the following solution, which works well:

```
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


  myData <- reactive({

    conn <- odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=xxx;database=xxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx")

    q <- paste("SELECT * FROM dbo.players")

    res <- sqlQuery(channel=conn, query=q)

    odbcClose(conn)

    res

  })

  output$view <- renderTable({
    head(myData(), input$rows) # render only the first (input$rows) rows
  })
})
```